# Semantically identical codes give different results

Tags: c, io

I couldn't wrap my head around this one, hope the title isn't too misleading. Why does `write` behave differently when it comes to it's third argument `count` in the two snippets of code? It would seem that calling a function instead of specifying a number in `write` is a bad thing, but it doesn't seem like a big deal.

Wrong version:

```
   int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    char    format[50];         
    char    formattedTime[50];  
    time_t      t;              



    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, format, 50) < 0)
        fatalError("read() error");



    time(&t);   

    strftime(formattedTime, 50, format, localtime(&t));


    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, formattedTime, strlen(formattedTime) + 1) != strlen(formattedTime) + 1)
        fatalError("write() error");



    return 0;
}
```

Right version:

```
   int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    char    format[50];         //zeljeni format
    char    formattedTime[50];  //formatirano vreme
    time_t      t;              // trenutno vreme

    // citamo s ulaza zeljeni format vremena

    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, format, 50) < 0)
        fatalError("read() error");


    // zapisujemo trenutno vreme
    time(&t);   

    strftime(formattedTime, 50, format, localtime(&t));

    int n;
    n = strlen(formattedTime) + 1;

    // ispisujemo na izlaz
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, formattedTime, n) != n)
        fatalError("write() error");



    return 0;
}
```

Right output:

```
%a %b %d
Wed Jan 16
```

Wrong output:

```
%a %b %d
Wed Jan 16
0
```

Why would calcuating `n` just a step before the call to `write` make all the difference?

**EDIT:**
Hope this satisfies all the info. The gibberish is different every time, but the point remains.

Comment: It works fine for me if I have `char *formattedTime = "Wed Jan 16";`.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us? Something we can copy-paste to try ourselves?

Comment: What is the exact value of `formattedTime` and how is it obtained?

Comment: You need to check the return value of `strftime` too. If it returns 0 the contents of the buffer are undefined.

Comment: The `read` call doesn't att the null-terminator to the string you read. Because of that you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when calling `strftime`.

Comment: Furthermore, *never* read format strings from a user. That is an enormous security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` function is primarily intended to read binary data, not strings.  As such, it reads only the characters you enter (i.e. a sequence of characters followed by a newline) without adding a null terminating byte.  As a result, you don't have a properly formatted string, so using `strftime` can read past what was written into bytes that were not initialized and possibly past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The "right version" seems to work because you got "lucky".  That's one of the ways undefined behavior can manifest itself.  Other people could see the opposite results of what you see.

You need to capture how many bytes were read and manually add a terminating null byte to the array:

```
int rval;

if ((rval=read(STDIN_FILENO, format, 49)) < 0)
    fatalError("read() error");

 format[rval] = 0;
```

Comment: Alright then, I just wanna get this out of the way:
When I input `%a %b %d[ENTER KEY]` what does `read` actually read ?

Comment: @monolith937 It reads a total of 9 characters (the 8 characters of the format plus a newline) and puts that into `format`.  It does *not* write a null byte because it doesn't know it's reading a string.

Comment: so when using `read` to fetch something that I need as a string for later, I should always (manually) insert a `\0` byte at the end ?

Comment: @monolith937 Correct.  As such, you should instead use something like `fgets` which it intended to read strings, ex. `fgets(format, sizeof(format), stdin);`

Answer (score 3):

If you really have that behavior this probably means the null character is missing in *formattedTime* and by chance *n* is just after in the stack and introduces a null char by its presence, or an equivalent because of the data saved in the stack